# ng-view will not auto hide address/navigation bar on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, mobile

I am building a mobile website using [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/). After almost completion I tried to finally test it on my mobile devices. I realized that: when I scroll down the page, the navigation bar of the browser(i.e. Safari on iPhone, Chrome on Android devices) does not auto hide like it used to function when browsing normal websites.

Such as these website:

[Mobile Angular UI Demo](http://mobileangularui.com/demo/#/) (My project's index.html is almost identical to this index.html)

[wReader](http://vojtajina.github.io/WebApp-CodeLab/FinalProject/)

Is there fix? Or is just a disadvantage of ng-view and I am going to have to deal with it?

Any outputs are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could do that by using `$routechangesuccess` event of $routeProvider..

Comment: Weird. Even using `Angular Material` causes the browser url bar to remain open at all times.

Comment: @pankajparkar care to elaborate please?

Comment: I was telling you fix of this issue.for that you need to `$rootScope.$on` event with nav name $routeChangeSuccess which will be called on after route changes occur..this event will live inside run block..you need to right side menu close event code inside this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be solved, unfortunately, unless you want to use a different theme or make your own.

This is caused by the CSS. By default, scrolling in Mobile Safari doesn't feel native—the page scrolls more slowly compared to native apps.

In order to get smoother, bouncy, native-feeling iOS scrolling, a parent element (either a `div` or `body`) with a height of 100% of the window height is used and it has an `overflow-y: scroll` property.

Also, some of your theme's features (like the slide-out nav) may require this CSS implementation to work properly.

When scrolling, you are scrolling inside of that element—you are not scrolling the page. Mobile Safari will shrink the address bar when the page scrolls but when this CSS is added, it is detecting that the page does not need to scroll (because the parent element of all of the elements is 100% the height of the window and does not exceed that). This means that the page isn't scrolling and instead a child element on the page has content that is scrolling), Mobile Safari does not detect page scrolling. This cannot be changed. I have a similar implementation on [my website](http://tinaciousdesign.com).

I made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/qdjWQN) that shows how this effect is made. Due to the body (grey) not needing to scroll—because it is 500px tall which is less than the window height—the scrolling happens in one of the elements that allows scrolling. Mobile Safari doesn't know that you want this parent element to act like the whole page so unfortunately this can't be fixed. In the above pen, the blue element is the parent element that simulates the whole page. The child elements are just there to add height/scrollable content.

Comment: Bad news :(  but the confusion is cleared with your explanation, thanks!